# XlsxWriter set global font size

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

How do permanently set the font size using xlswriter when you first create the workbook?

I tried:

```
book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(os.getcwd() + '\\test.xlsx')
sheet1 = book.add_worksheet()
format = book.add_format()
format.set_font_size(10)
```

But I still get the default size 11 in the output. What is the issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1, For single cell font size, you have to pass the `format` to the `write` like this:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
# Add a font size 10 format.
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_font_size(10)
# Write some simple text.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello', format)

# Text with formatting.
worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)


workbook.close()
```

`Hello` will be set to font size `10`.

[image]

**Update:**
2, For all cells font size, you could set the default format of the workbook:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')

# default cell format to size 10 
workbook.formats[0].set_font_size(10)

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


# Write some simple text.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

worksheet.write('A2', 'World')

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)

workbook.close()
```

All cell will change to font size 10:

[image]

Comment: is there any way to set this globally? I write many times to this worksheet / book and I want to avoid passing it every time since I want it all size 10

Comment: The workaround is okay but note that it breaks the sizing of images, graphs and other objects inserted into the worksheet. This is the main reason that this feature isn't currently supported in XlsxWriter.

Comment: @jmcnamara Thanks for your comments about this point, it is very important for us to know about it.

Comment: Thanks, but this still actually doesn't work. Is it possible when writing with different font colors, this sizing gets reset?

Comment: yes, it will overwrite the font size to be 11, if you add other format like `set_font_color` and `set_bold`.

Comment: Is it possible then to set it at the end using your method? Like when I am done writing everything, just change the font size to 10.

Comment: For more info - https://groups.google.com/g/python-excel/c/0vWPLht7K64